# Confused about decomposition in Context Free Pumping lemma

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, proof-techniques, pumping-lemma

I am trying to decide whether the following language is context free:

$$L = \{ a^nb^{3n}c^n \, | \, n \geq 0 \} $$

Assume $L$ is context-free.
Let $p$ be the pumping length given by the Pumping Lemma.
Choose string $s = a^pb^{3p}c^p ∈ L$. Then, $|s| ≥ p$.
Take an arbitrary decomposition $s = uvxyz$ where $|vxy| \le p$ and $|vy| > 0$.

Case 1:

i. $v,y ∈ a^*$

ii. $v,y ∈ b^*$

iii. $v,y ∈ c^*$

Here, uv0xy0z ∉ L, due to incorrect number of symbols.

Case 3:
i. $$v ∈ aa* and y ∈ bb*$$
ii. $$v ∈ bb* and y ∈ cc*$$

Here, uv0xy0z ∉ L, since #a's ≠ #c's.

So, s cannot be pumped, which contradicts the Pumping Lemma. Hence, L is not context-free.

However, after checking my answer, it seems that I missed that I missed one case where:

$$ v ∈ aa^*bb^* or \,\,y ∈ aa^*bb^* $$
$$ v ∈ bb^*cc^* or \,\,y ∈ bb^*cc^* $$

Here, uv2xy2z ∉ L, due to incorrect ordering of symbols.

But this doesn't make sense to me; how can this mess up the ordering of the symbols because wouldn't it follow that for example X would be the symbols after v?

Thanks guys,

Comment: Could someone fix my equations at the end also btw; I'm not sure why it didn't format correctly.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: Note that in math mode you need to use `\{`, rather than `{`.  Also in math mode, use `*` rather than `\*`.

Comment: I edited the beginning of the question to help, but please edit the rest to make it readable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.